# Lua adding package.path to require doesn't work

Tags: lua, love2d

Here is my folder structure:

src/config/objects/bird.lua

src/objects/Bird.lua

In Bird.lua, I tried to import src/config/objects/bird.lua by using:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';../config/objects/?.lua'
local BIRD = require("bird")
```

But it doesn't work and no module is found. What I'm doing wrong ?

Here is my error screen:

[image: module not found]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. Love2d run the main.lua file, so that path in `require` must be relative to main.lua. And because my main.lua is at the root folder, I just need to use:

```
local BIRD = require("src.config.objects.bird")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package.path = package.path .. ';../config/objects/?.lua'
```

This should work.

Comment: I have tried it before and it doesn't work. Sorry for my lack of information. I will update the question

Comment: If you put just one dot, will it work? `package.path = package.path .. ';./config/objects/?.lua'`

Comment: I have found the solution. The path in the ```require``` must be relative to the main.lua. And my main.lua is at the root folder, so I just need to write ```local BIRD = require("src.config.objects.bird")```. Thank you for your help